# Como formatar dinheiro com jade no node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jade

Tenho que apresentar valores monetários em minha view, porém está aparecendo sem formatação. Por exemplo, `5.4237` deveria ser apresentado como `R$ 5,42`, porém não sei como formatar esse valor usando o **Jade com node.js**.

Eu preciso que o valor fique salvo no sistema como um número puro, sem formatação, pois esse número é usado em cálculos que perderiam a precisão caso fosse salvo apenas com duas casas decimais. Porém, para mostrar o valor na tela eu não preciso das demais casas decimais, por isso creio que a melhor forma será formatar o valor no momento de mostrá-lo para o usuário.

Como faço para formatar esses valores monetários em jade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem vários pacotes no `npm` que podem servir pro que você precisa:

- [Numeral](https://www.npmjs.com/package/numeral)
- [Accounting](https://www.npmjs.com/package/accounting)
- [Format As Currency](https://www.npmjs.com/package/format-as-currency)

O Jade em si não tem uma estrutura especial para conversão em formato monetário.

### Exemplo:

```
// Adiciona o middleware accounting ao contexto da view.
data["accounting"] = require('accounting');

<!-- Chama o objeto accounting para formatar o valor monetário. -->
p Total = #{accounting.formatMoney(5.4237, "R$ ", 2, ",", ".")}
```

Resultado obtido:
    Total = **R$ 5,42**

Comment: Pois é. Estou adicionando o accounting ao contexto do template e chamando o método de formatação dentro da view, mas queria uma forma mais "nativa" de fazer isso. Se não tiver, o jeito vai ser usar assim mesmo.

Comment: Pois é. Não tem. O Jade é mais um template HTML que uma suíte gráfica completa.

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado pela resposta.